# How the bscscan Dex Trades works?

Tags: web3js, events, decentralized-exchange, bscscan

I'm trying to get transaction logs of a token on all Dex Exchange (.e.g Pancakeswap) like below.

[image]

I captured it from https://bscscan.com/token/0x78a499a998bdd5a84cf8b5abe49100d82de12f1c#tokenTrade

** What did I do:

1. I used web3 to get logs of event **Transfer** of that token address but result includes transactions that irrelevant to my goal. For example:

```js
  const contract = contracts.getERC20Token(TOKEN_ADDRESS.JOJO);
  const events = await contract.getPastEvents('Transfer', {
    fromBlock: 16625075,
    toBlock: 16626395,
  });
  const txHash = [];
  const groupedTx = events.reduce((result, event) => {
    const tx = event.transactionHash;
    if (!result[tx]) {
      txHash.push(tx);
      result[tx] = { events: [event.event] };
    } else {
      result[tx].events.push(event.event);
    }
    return result;
  }, {});
  console.log(groupedTx, txHash);
```

```
groupedTx {
  '0x889431072aaf2e02760c41db896d27dc02e5bbc2254599461ae1259f26c7b82c': {
    events: [ 'Transfer', 'Transfer', 'Transfer', 'Transfer', 'Transfer' ]
  },
  '0x541ad23879bfb526c2ad5265eb68773a8d48deaeead89adc74791009c0ce49a5': { events: [ 'Transfer', 'Transfer', 'Transfer', 'Transfer' ] },
  '0x8530b5dcf92b1f561db994e9591a03c17eeadc5335fe1f470e2fd90d1bc8df94': { events: [ 'Transfer', 'Transfer', 'Transfer', 'Transfer' ] },
  '0x514ee1c90bbdaa34d9bdfd66a5e531560d4712cf0fe6f300569ef5cd98b39cab': { events: [ 'Transfer' ] },
  '0xae3ab69a1e2f70ff3b5098b9f55325d890523448a816c39035782dd4ae028533': { events: [ 'Transfer', 'Transfer' ] },
  '0xf165d4687655af3aeae557708ac52f139d9f8876af8ba0d6bb504522e659ab32': {
    events: [ 'Transfer', 'Transfer', 'Transfer', 'Transfer', 'Transfer' ]
  },
  '0x307c006a5f78db88a19253d029623ef22f2fac70d0bdd049378bec8c637679fa': { events: [ 'Transfer', 'Transfer', 'Transfer', 'Transfer' ] },
  '0xdc3738e78f8ea26a33a6eb0fe8f5b3db715378d504125d73d34d21c32a25add7': { events: [ 'Transfer' ] },
  '0xa5a803803c427873ebc88512538163846103160472ab8ae8022fe00bf030938e': { events: [ 'Transfer', 'Transfer', 'Transfer', 'Transfer' ] },
  '0x952438d50a6d99fb400234ecbe7e8a6e7a3806e511049c01d18270e65eccca2f': { events: [ 'Transfer', 'Transfer', 'Transfer', 'Transfer' ] },
  '0x3f5aa67db230599634939f03edec7baf85c1793be37ba5b7f3c3daf1b6858860': { events: [ 'Transfer', 'Transfer', 'Transfer', 'Transfer' ] },
  '0xf5f5463b8c0c105dd18142c8c6f1d54c447e296b536b679d3db33b87d8eae3c0': { events: [ 'Transfer' ] }
}
txHash [
  '0x889431072aaf2e02760c41db896d27dc02e5bbc2254599461ae1259f26c7b82c',
  '0x541ad23879bfb526c2ad5265eb68773a8d48deaeead89adc74791009c0ce49a5',
  '0x8530b5dcf92b1f561db994e9591a03c17eeadc5335fe1f470e2fd90d1bc8df94',
  '0x514ee1c90bbdaa34d9bdfd66a5e531560d4712cf0fe6f300569ef5cd98b39cab',
  '0xae3ab69a1e2f70ff3b5098b9f55325d890523448a816c39035782dd4ae028533',
  '0xf165d4687655af3aeae557708ac52f139d9f8876af8ba0d6bb504522e659ab32',
  '0x307c006a5f78db88a19253d029623ef22f2fac70d0bdd049378bec8c637679fa',
  '0xdc3738e78f8ea26a33a6eb0fe8f5b3db715378d504125d73d34d21c32a25add7',
  '0xa5a803803c427873ebc88512538163846103160472ab8ae8022fe00bf030938e',
  '0x952438d50a6d99fb400234ecbe7e8a6e7a3806e511049c01d18270e65eccca2f',
  '0x3f5aa67db230599634939f03edec7baf85c1793be37ba5b7f3c3daf1b6858860',
  '0xf5f5463b8c0c105dd18142c8c6f1d54c447e296b536b679d3db33b87d8eae3c0'
] 12
```

The result show that there are 12 transactions from block 16625075 to block 16626395 but on bscscan it only 4 relevant transactions.

2. I tried to use 3rd party service like Bitquery to get the logs. It gave the same result on bscscan but it's costly and I don't found the subscription function to get real time data when new transaction triggered.
   I saw poocoin shows real-time transactions from BSC provider (bsc-dataseed1.defibit.io) but don't know how they do  https://poocoin.app/tokens/0x78a499a998bdd5a84cf8b5abe49100d82de12f1c

I'm stuck and don't know what to do next to solve the problem. I really appreciate your help.